# jQuery POST AJAX => No Response Header

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a problem with a jQuery AJAX call. Sometimes it works and sometimes I don't get any response from the server. The passed parameters are correct, but no callback function will be invoked except for `beforeSend`. I don't even get a HTTP Response Header from the server. 
The request header seems to be correct and looks exactly like one of the correct calls.
Any Suggestions?

**[UPDATE]**
Ok, here is a code snippet and a request header, but i don't think, that this is a implementation problem... FYI: I've deleted the cookie values in the request header

```
jQuery.ajax
        (
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php?eID=doSomeStuff',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:
                {
                    obj_php_config: obj_php_config,
                    obj_php_search: obj_php_search,
                    selectedBox: selectedBox
                },
                error:
                    function (obj, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
                    },
                success:
                    function (data, textStatus)
                    {
                         doSomeStuffWithData(data);
                       }

            }
        );
```

```
Host              myDomain.loc
User-Agent        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept            application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Language   en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive        115
Connection        keep-alive
Content-Type      application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest
Referer           http://myDomain.loc/aSite.html?page=1
Content-Length    567
Cookie            --redacted by user--
```

Comment: I suggest you post some code. :)

Comment: make sure that you are not doing any cross-domain ajax call...

Comment: thanks for the comments. I've posted a code snippet above... but there aren't any cross-domain calls

Comment: The server side code will not be executed.

Comment: So you're seeing those headers where? There should be *some* kind of response shown, somewhere, even if it's a 404 or a 5xx or something.

Comment: @Philipp: (Deleted my answer, since half of it was out of date and the other half didn't help.) Yeah, I didn't really think the "utf-8" thing would work. :-( See my question above: Where are you seeing those headers? You should be seeing *something* in terms of a response if you're looking at Firebug or Chrome's dev tools or similar, even if it's a timeout or a 500 or...

Comment: @T.J.: I don't get any response from server. Neither 404 nor some kind of 5xx.... There is only a POST Error in the Console Tab of Firebug.

Comment: @T.J. There is something more I found out. Recapitulation: 1. There is NO server response. Most of the time the NET tab shows me a "?" instead of server response. 2. there is only a POST Error in Console tab of Firebug 3. Due to lack of an error message, the AJAX-call will invoke the success callback function... and then the javascript fails. But this is only a subsequent error.... 4. There aren't any specific notes/messages about the reasons of the POST Error.

Comment: @Philipp: Very strange. Can you post the *exact* text of the POST error from the console? (Most consoles should allow copying the text to the clipboard, you may have to select it first.)

Comment: @T.J.: Yeah, this is very odd. I've never seen anything like this before. There is only a red line in the console tab with a text like "POST http://myFoo.bar/snafu.php?eid=aParam". This looks very similar to a valid POST request in the console tab. Of course I can view the details of this request by clicking the "+", but the information I got there are exactly the same that I got from a valid request, except for the response header and the response. Response header and response are just empty

Comment: @Philipp: I'd recommend trying it with Chrome's dev tools (if you're currently using Firebug), or with Firebug (if you're currently using Chrome's dev tools), etc. -- e.g., an alternate debugger. See if it gives you more information. Separately: If you're using Firebug, I had a problem a while back where it frankly seemed to just get confused, completely exiting Firefox and starting fresh cleared it up. (I've had that with Chrome, too. Rare in both cases.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realise this post is pretty old now but wanted to post to help others. I just resolved a similar (if not the same) issue.

The problem in my case was that the same click event that triggered the AJAX post (via jquery event binding) was redirecting the page using href. Therefore the post didn't actually fail but was interrupted, I assume this is why there is no response info.

In short - check to make sure a redirect is not being triggered anywhere.

Depending on the timing of the page redirection, the call might work correctly from time to time. I guess?

Anyways, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You know -- I actually had a very similar problem come to think of it.. and I still to this day am not sure exactly why..

I replaced the $.ajax call with

```
$.post( 'url being called',
       { key:value},
       function (response) {
           // handle success/error response
       }
);
```

I really don't know how this makes any difference though.

---

Does firebug give you any error status? the NET information tab is extremely useful when working with Ajax.

Some code would be nice

EDIT: If you're doing any cross domain posts you'll need to using json with padding

Comment: there is no error in the NET tab of Firebug. There is only a POST Error in the Console Tab, but I don't know how to handle that... the Domain is reachable, it's not a cross-domain call and sometimes it works...

Comment: *I really don't know how this makes any difference though."* No. `$.post` is purely a wrapper for `$.ajax` with `method: 'POST'`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post

Answer (score 0):

be sure that your server responses this way:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("test" => "test"));
exit;
```

second guess, regarding the POST error, maybe invalid obj keys in your data obj, add quotes:

```
{
"obj_php_config": obj_php_config,
"obj_php_search": obj_php_search,
selectedBox: selectedBox
},
```

Comment: The keys in his object literal are not reserved words and are legal identifiers, so the quotes are unnecessary. You only *need* quotes when using a reserved word (like "for") or a key with invalid identifer characters (like "[]"). (They don't do any harm, they just don't make any difference. This is an object literal, not JSON.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on this, the problem I had was my url was being redirected or it was CANCELLED by one of my chrome extension, **Adblock**...
the url was matching ***/post_save_advert/**

It worked after disabling chrome extension for the specific site.
I then also renamed it from save_advert to another url so it wont be blocked again.